# BCP file format for SQL bulk insert of CSV file

Tags: sql, csv, insert, bcp, bulk

I'm trying a bulk insert of a csv file into a SQL table using BCP but can't fix this error: "The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 2. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly." - Can anyone help please?

Here's my SQL code:

```
BULK INSERT UKPostCodeStaging
FROM 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Data\TestFileOf2Records.csv'
WITH (
DATAFILETYPE='char',
FIRSTROW = 1,
FORMATFILE = 'C:\Users\User\UKPostCodeStaging.fmt');
```

Here's my test data contained in TestFileOf2Records.csv:

> "HS1 2AA",10,14,93,"S923","","S814","","S1213","S132605"
>   "HS1 2AD",10,14,93,"S923","","S814","","S1213","S132605"

And here's my BCP file that I have attempted to edit appropriately:

```
10.0
11
1   SQLCHAR  0  0  "\""      0  FIRST_QUOTE                 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2   SQLCHAR  8  0  "\","     1  PostCode                    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3   SQLINT   1  0  ","       2  PositionalQualityIndicator  ""
4   SQLINT   1  0  ","       3  MetresEastOfOrigin          ""
5   SQLINT   1  0  ",\""     4  MetresNorthOfOrigin         ""
6   SQLCHAR  8  0  "\",\""   5  CountryCode                 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7   SQLCHAR  8  0  "\",\""   6  NHSRegionalHACode           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
8   SQLCHAR  8  0  "\",\""   7  NHSHACode                   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
9   SQLCHAR  8  0  "\",\""   8  AdminCountyCode             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
10  SQLCHAR  8  0  "\",\""   9  AdminDistrictCode           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
11  SQLCHAR  8  0  "\"\r\n"  10 AdminWardCode               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?
thanks

Comment: quote qualifier make bulk insert a hell job this way.load the data using , as field terminator(you dont need to use format file in this case) and then use replace() function to remove quotes from the data.

Comment: Thanks - I have done that to get the data loaded this time. However it would be good to know how to get the BCP file right as I don't want to apply a manual fix every time the data is updated.