# Pivot table into multiple columns and multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Background**
I am have a table which contains a varchar with a comma separated string (which has multiple rows similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695803/sql-server-read-csv-binary-from-table) question. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a way to change a csv varchar into a temp table simply so I am looking into splitting it up myself. (I would also appreciate any answers tackling this, although maybe it should be a separate question?).

**Question**

I have successfully split the string up and am now producing an output similar to:

```
   -------------------------------------
   | Row Index  | Column Index | Value |
   -------------------------------------
   |     0      |      0       | (0,0) |
   |     0      |      1       | (1,0) |
   |     0      |      2       | (2,0) |
   |     1      |      0       | (0,1) |
   |     1      |      1       | (1,1) |
   |     1      |      2       | (2,1) |
   |     2      |      0       | (0,2) |
   |     2      |      1       | (1,2) |
   |     2      |      2       | (2,2) |
   -------------------------------------
```

I would like to pivot this so that I can insert it into a temp table and the final result would look like:

```
   -------------------------------------
   | Column 1  | Column 2  | Column 3  |
   -------------------------------------
   |   (0,0)   |   (1,0)   |   (2,0)   |
   |   (0,1)   |   (1,1)   |   (2,1)   |
   |   (0,2)   |   (1,2)   |   (2,2)   |
   -------------------------------------
```

**Asides**

1. The number of columns is known ahead of time but answers which don't depend on this are also welcome.
2. I know that I could repeatedly left outer join the first table to get this result but this requires outer joining once for every column (as I have ~9 columns this will be a lot of repetition) and I assume that there is another way.
3. Performance is not key but there will be ~2000 rows with 8 columns in the final table.

Comment: You may want to read this article that explains the canonical SQL pivot technique: http://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: Cheers Markus, I've had to tackle this issue before and wish I had come across that then (I previously had to go with the JOIN multiple times method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    RowIndex
  , Column1 = max(case when ColumnIndex=0 then Value end)
  , Column2 = max(case when ColumnIndex=1 then Value end)
  , Column3 = max(case when ColumnIndex=2 then Value end)
from t
group by RowIndex
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/QLPHR39222

returns:

```
+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| RowIndex | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
+----------+---------+---------+---------+
|        0 | (0,0)   | (1,0)   | (2,0)   |
|        1 | (0,1)   | (1,1)   | (2,1)   |
|        2 | (0,2)   | (1,2)   | (2,2)   |
+----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

---

or with `pivot()`:

```
select 
    RowIndex
  , Column1 = [0]
  , Column2 = [1]
  , Column3 = [2]
from t
pivot (max(Value) for ColumnIndex in ([0],[1],[2])) p
```

Comment: Thanks SqlZim, I saw similar answers all over the place but didn't think to add the group by to get multiple rows. I'm going to leave it a bit longer so i can have a play around and see if anyone has any other answers

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward application of a PIVOT query ([See The Docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)):

```
select x.[0] Column1
     , x.[1] Column2
     , x.[2] Column3
  from YourData
 pivot (max(Value)
   for [Column Index]
    in ([0], [1], [2]) ) x
 order by x.[Row Index]
```

which Returns:

```
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
|---------|---------|---------|
|   (0,0) |   (1,0) |   (2,0) |
|   (0,1) |   (1,1) |   (2,1) |
|   (0,2) |   (1,2) |   (2,2) |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba0139/1)

To add more columns simply add more column indexes to the `FOR column IN (list)` section, and add the same values to the projection (select list)

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't quite get my head around the docs. I'll take a look at your example and try to make sure it sticks.